# Convert words to links in product description

Tags: php, mysql

I have an eccomerce site with product descriptions and sometimes a product will describe another product on the site and i want a way to link to the other product without manually putting the `<a>` tag in the description.

I was thinking maybe have the description compared against my product database to see if any of the words match a product name, but im not sure how to go about that and if it would be to much load on the mysql database to check everytime the page loads.

I was thinking to `explode` the whitespace in the description, but some products have spaces in them so i dont think that would work.

Comment: Are the product names sufficiently unique that there wouldn't be many false positives? A simple str_replace loop could easily make words/phrases into links.

Comment: My answer takes such an approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this as follows.

Have a list of all your product names in an array. You could cache this using [APC](http://php.net/apc), [memcache](http://php.net/memcache) or the like if you do not want to query the database for this everytime you render a page.

Do a simple string replacement when you're rendering the site. The result can also be cached either using the mechanisms named above or -- in case you're using one that supports this -- with help of the template system's caching functionality.

However, beware of false positives due to overly broad product names.

Simplistic example:

```
// product names and links (from db or cache)
$products = array('Flux Capacitor' => 'http://example.com/fluxcapacitor/');
// unprocessed content
$content = 'Lorem ipsum Flux Capacitor bla foo bar flux.';
// TODO apply htmlspecialchars, htmlentities or whatever you
// (this needs to be done BEFORE you insert links)
foreach($products as $name => $link){
   $content = str_replace($name, '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$name.'</a>', $content);
}
// 'Flux Capacitor' now should link to its product site. Let's echo the content.
echo $content;
```

Comment: "However, beware of false positives due to overly broad product names." thats the problem im running into now.

Comment: So don't do it for all products, but only for those with specific names? Alternatively, use some kind of marker, e.g. `#Flux Capacitor#` (this requires you to edit all your legacy content).